# Can I split a Mercurial repository?

Tags: version-control, mercurial

I have a largish Mercurial repository that I've decided would be better as several smaller repositories.  Is there a way that I can split the repository and have each piece retain its revision history?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

The best way to do this is using the ['convert' extension](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/ConvertExtension).  You'll use mercurial and both source and destination type and then use a `--filemap` with entries like:

```
exclude path/you/do/not/want
rename path/you/do/want .
```

The rename is only necessary if you want to take the parts you're keeping and move them "higher" in the directory hierarchy.

Comment: This wont work: rename path/you/do/want /
This will: rename path/you/do/want .
This only applies if you are moving a path to the root.

Comment: Even better: replace the `exclude ...` line with `include path/you/do/want` -- then only the named path(s) will make it into the converted repo.

Comment: @Kevin that's definitely the way to do it if you want the projects to stay in their original, deep, paths.  I figured that since splitting was the goal that each project should be raised to the top level of the new repo in which it's the sole project.

Comment: I used this `convert` extension and was at first wondering why the destination path seems empty. Then I realized that there is no working copy by default in the new repo. If you need it, you should run `hg up` in the destination directory. Maybe it will help someone.

Answer (score 0):

I found a detailed guide [here](http://510x.se/notes/posts/Splitting_a_Mercurial_repository_while_keeping_relevant_history/):

Create a file map `new-repo.filemap` such as

```
include vendor/FooBackend
rename vendor/FooBackend .
```

Create another file map `rewrite-old-repo.filemap`:

```
exclude vendor/FooBackend
```

Create the new repository:

```
hg convert /path/to/current/repo /path/to/new/repo --filemap new-repo.filemap
```

The new repository is now finished. The directory is empty, but a `hg update` will bring its contents up to speed.

Create the modified repository:

```
hg convert /path/to/current/repo /path/to/rewritten/repo --filemap rewrite-old-repo.filemap
```

Comment: This looks interesting for splitting a Mercurial repo in two, but it seems like it would get too complicated if for instance I have a project with over 200 sub-directories and I want to turn each sub-directory into its own project. (It's not entirely clear whether I would simply "include" and "rename" the directory I wanted to keep, and then exclude the other 200+, or if I would need to iterate each file in the sub-directory.

Answer (score -5):

Just clone it and delete the unwanted stuff out of each copy.

Comment: That doesn't help.  Every close still has full history, so the "too much stuff" will always be there in the ".hg" directory taking up space.

Comment: ah, you want the Stalinist revisionism form of version control. ;)
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Historical_revisionism_(negationism)

Comment: @Ry4an But aren't the clones efficient copies of each other? Meaning yes, the revision history for the deleted items will be in both repositories but only stored once on disk right? So if I cloned a repository with several revs to files A - D and then deleted to give me an A/B and C/D repository, I'd only be storing one copy of all the revs of A-D along with an extra changeset in each one indicating C/D were removed in one and A/B in the other. Right?

Comment: @adam yes, provided they all local clones storage will be efficient. It sounded like the original questioner wanted to be able to clone the subset repos to new (non-local) locations and have those clones be smaller.  That's only possible by modifying history.