# How to prevent divergent mercurial branches from merging?

Tags: version-control, mercurial

I have a project stored in mercurial which has grown well beyond its original remit, and now I want to split the repository into two separate projects.  Say the file tree looks something like this:

```
src/
  a/
    a.h
    a.c
  b/
    b.h
    b.c
```

Say I've `hg clone`d this repository twice, and in the first clone I've performed an `hg rm src/b/*`, and in the second I've performed an `hg rm src/a/*`.  This gives me the two separate source trees I want, with history and revision numbering preserved in each branch.

The problem I now have is what happens if, in the future, I ever accidentally pull from the a/ clone into the b/ clone.  What I'd like is for mercurial to simply refuse to pull from, or push to, the other branch, if I ever try to do so, as if the two had never shared history.

Is this possible? If not, is there a canonical way to create two parallel projects from one original which preserves history and revision numbering?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The canonical way would be to use [hg convert](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/ConvertExtension) with a filemap like this:

```
exclude b
rename a .
```

(and afterwards with the roles of `a` and `b` reversed to create the second repository)

This way you end up with two unrelated repositories (which Mercurial will refuse to push/pull without the use of force) only containing the history of a single directory.

Also see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/257767/can-i-split-a-mercurial-repository) question for reference.