# Error when splitting a mercurial repository

Tags: mercurial, bitbucket, mercurial-convert

I have a mercurial repository hosted on bitbucket containing several folders. My goal was to split each of these folder into a separate repository. After trying a few things suggested on stackoverflow, which failed, my last throw of the dice was to replicate a mock example in the [bitbucket tutorial](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/Split+a+repository+in+two#Splitarepositoryintwo-UsingMercurialtoSplit-outaDirectory)

Even though I followed the instructions to the letter, this also failed:

```
hg convert -s hg -d hg --filemap mymapfile hgsplitpractice hgfreshrepo
initializing destination hgfreshrepo repository
hgsplitpractice is not a local Mercurial repository
abort: hgsplitpractice: missing or unsupported repository
```

This is the same error that appeared in my previous attempts to split my actual repo.

The questions are:
1. why is this failing?
2. is there any other way to split these repositories?

Comment: `hgsplitpractice` isn't Mercurial repo obviously

Comment: hgsplitpractice was created with hg clone, as suggested in the help pages. How is it not a mercurial repo @LazyBadger?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use the [convert extension](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/ConvertExtension).

After the command:

```
--filemap
```

you can use:

```
exclude path/that/you/want/to/split
rename path/that/you/want/to/split .
```

See this thread for more: [Can I split a Mercurial repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/257767/can-i-split-a-mercurial-repository)

Comment: I did see that thread and I believe it was my starting point. There is already a file mymapfile containing the line "include bigdir" in my main repo folder. After including the lines "exclude lildir
exclude lildir2" it still gives the same error.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error as you did.
In my case, the problem was something really silly: I was referring to both repositories by their names instead of specifying their full path.
I hope it helps someone else.

This was failing:

```
hg convert -s hg -d hg --filemap mymapfile "My-old-repo" "New-repo"
```

This worked like a charm:

```
hg convert -s hg -d hg --filemap mymapfile "d:/allrepos/My-old-repo" "d:/allrepos/New-repo"
```